# File not being created in file explorer

Tags: android, eclipse

I had this working all of the sudden it stopped working but the App runs without crashing, the only problem is that the file is not created in file explorer of the DDMS of Eclipse.  Please help.
Thanks

```
//path to file

String clientList ="data/data/com.example.jaimepersonaltrainer2/files/ClientList.txt";



FileWriter fos;
        try {               
            fos = new FileWriter(clientList,true);
            BufferedWriter buffOut = new BufferedWriter(fos);

            for(String s: clientNamesArrayList){

                buffOut.write(s);

        }
            buffOut.flush();
            buffOut.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps it is a problem of permission. I had similar problems before.

Comment: I've looked in permissions.  This has me stuck don't know why one second it works the next it stops without changing anything(code).